# Doing a search function on a txt file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, webforms, full-text-search

I am trying to create a search function, so that when I search for White, it should return me "#FFFFFF". Also, it should be case insensitive and support partial name input. The text file that I have contains all the color coding information in the following format:

```
"#FFFFFF"#White: "#FF0000"#Red:
```

What I have managed to understand, and done so far is as below; which is basically mapping to the text file and instructing it to write to line till the end of the document. What I do not understand is how to implement the above requirements.

I know it is not a lot, but I don't understand the concept behind the search function.

```
 protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("colorCode.txt");
            string line = null;

           while((line =sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the file, I would perhaps consider reading in the entire contents of the file into a string and then using regular expressions to perform your search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example the `colorCode` stores the the match for the `colorToSearch`

```
    protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("colorCode.txt");
    string line = null;

    char []colorSeparator =  { ':' } ;
    string []colors ;

    char []colorCodeSeparator =  { '#' } ;
    string []codeAndColor ;

    bool found ;
    string colorToSearch ;
    string colorCode ;

    colorToSearch  = "White" ;
    found = false ;

    while(!found && (line =sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
    {
        //separate the content of the file "#FFFFFF"#White: "#FF0000"#Red: using ":" as separator
        colors = line.Split(colorSeparator) ;

        foreach(string color in colors)
        {
            codeAndColor = colors.Split(colorCodeSeparator) ;
            //codeAndColor[0] now contains the colorCode "#FFFFFF"
            //codeAndColor[1] contains the name of the color "White"

            //check if the name of the color in the file contains the colorToSearch allowing for case insensitive
            if(codeAndColor[1].ToUpper().Contains(colorToSearch.ToUpper()))
            {
                colorCode = codeAndColor[0].Substring(1,7) ; //the 1 is to skip the initial double quote, 7 is the number of caracter to take
                found = true ;
                //stop the foreach loop
                break ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are going to do more searches I suggest that you load the colors in a `Dictionary<string,string>` only once from the file and perform the search on the Dictionary

Comment: Hi Mauricio, can i just check with you what is the purpose of `bool found ;` is that meant to store the color ? and also what does `Substring(1,7) ;` do ?

Comment: Also does the implementation of the table looks like this ?
replacing `string []colors` ; with 
`var colors_store = new Dictionary<string, string>()`

Comment: @user2691544 variable "found" is just to avoid looking at the whole file, when found is true it breaks the foreach loop and the while loop, the found color is store in "colorCode" and the Substring(1,7) takes only the #234567 of the color code skipping the double quotes

Comment: This is what i have done up base on your suggestion.


           ` while (!found && (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                countries = line.Split(colorSeparator );

                foreach (string color in colors)
                {
                    if (color.IndexOf(color_search))
                    {

                        color_code = color;
                        found = false;
                       
                        Label2.Text = country_code;

                    }`

Comment: Sorry about it. I found your code easier to understand eventually. With regards to displaying all related search instead of just one line, how do i do it ? Example a search of "B" should yield result of all "B" such as blue, black, brown.

Comment: @user2691544 do you need it to be case senstive or insensitive (like searching for "B" should return "blue") ? the contains checks for escenarios like the one you mention but is case sensitive, which means you have to look for "b" to find "blue" and "black"

Comment: @user2691544 I just updated the source code to allow for case insentive search which should work for the scenarios that you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening the file every time, if the file is not huge and it is not updated while your program is running, perhaps you can read it just once and create a lookup table that can be searched, like in the example below. If you need case insensitive comparisons, or a more complicated way to do partial color matching, you will need to add that.

```
public class ColorLookUpTable
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _colorTable;

    private ColorLookUpTable(IDictionary<string, string> colorTable)
    {
        _colorTable = colorTable;
    }

    public static ColorLookUpTable LoadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        var colorTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var colorPairs = line
                    .Split(new [] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Where(f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f))
                    .Select(f => f.Trim());
                foreach (var colorPair in colorPairs)
                {
                    var fields = colorPair.Split(new [] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
                    if (fields.Length == 2)
                        colorTable[fields[1]] = colorTable[fields[0]];
                }
            }
        }
        return new ColorLookUpTable(colorTable);
    }

    public string FindColorCodeExactMatch(string colorName)
    {
        string colorCode = null;
        if (_colorTable.TryGetValue(colorName, out colorCode))
            return colorCode;
        return null;
    }

    public string FindColorCodePartialMatch(string colorName)
    {
        var colorCode = FindColorCodeExactMatch(colorName);
        if (colorCode == null) // No exact match. Need to do work
            // very simple partial mathching.
            colorCode = _colorTable.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains(colorName)).FirstOrDefault();
        return colorCode;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myColorLookupTable = ColorLookUpTable.LoadFromFile("colorCode.txt");
var colorCode = myColorLookupTable.FindColorCodeExactMatch("White");
var another = myColorLookupTable.FindColorCodePartialMatch("ack");
```

Comment: CHeer mate. That is exactly what i am looking for.